# my emacs defaults stop working

Tags: emacs

Emacs was working fine, a few days ago some basic functions stopped working.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> 
go to start/end buffer used to work but now I get an undefined error.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> goto line. It was worked, now I get an undefined error

I can't paste into the mini buffer on search with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>, instead it paste the character that my cursor is on.

No one touched my .emacs file.

What is going on? I used emacs for along time and never had a problem with basic functions or pasting to the mini buffer.

### Update:

Latest update on my problem is that everything is working when I use the Esc key instead of the Alt key. I don't know why or how it changes but it has nothing to do with my .emacs file or CapsLock or key pressing mistakes. Has anybody a clue why it changes and how to change it back?

Comment: Can you provide some detail of error messages ?

Comment: the errorthat I get: <key combination> is undefined

Comment: Is your CAPS LOCK key on?

Comment: Check whether the key combination is the one you pressed

Comment: This doesn't sound like an emacs problem. Does this affect any other programs? Have you done anything with your OS-level keybindings?

Answer (score 1):

Some things to check:

- **Is your .emacs file loading at all?** Are any of the settings in your .emacs file taking effect? Alternately, try running `emacs --load /path/to/your/.emacs`. This will load the lisp code in your emacs file. If your settings get loaded now, then you need to move your `.emacs` into the right location so Emacs can pick it up.
- **Is another mode unbinding your keys?** To check this, go to (for example) your `*scratch*` buffer, which should be in `lisp-interaction-mode`, and try a shortcut.
- **Is your .emacs file broken somehow?** Try opening it, and commenting everything out but one binding. Then restart emacs and see what happens. If it works, keep uncommenting out sections (binary search is the way to go) to see what line breaks loading.
- **Are you sure you're pressing the right keys?** Hit `C-h c M-g g` to run `describe-key-briefly` to see what [keys you're pressing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Help.html), and what they're currently bound to.
- **Is something wrong with the lisp code to bind the keys?** I know this isn't likely, since it used to work, but try it anyway. Open up your `.emacs` and go to the line binding `M-g g`. Put your cursor *after* the closing parenthesis, then press `C-x C-e` to evaluate the s-expression containing the binding. Then, try the keyboard shortcut again. If it works, then something isn't loading your `.emacs` file correctly.

Comment: I think I'm on to sonthing, when I press M-g g what I get in the mini buffer is "C-M-g is undefined" as if I alsow pressed on Ctrl which I did not. it looks like my Ctrl button is always pressed!!! do you know how to cancel that?

Comment: @user1436801 try connecting a different keyboard? If even for the sake of taking that out of the way.

Comment: Does this happen in other programs? If you go into, for example, Firefox or Chrome, put your cursor in the url bar, and press `t`, do you open a new tab (as `C-t` would do), or does it put a `t` into the url bar?

Answer (score 1):

You can open your dot emacs and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>eval-buffer</kbd>. See if your dot emacs file works, or if there are any bugs.

Comment: I commented out most of my .emacs file that is not the problem. every key combination that I press adds the Ctrl key to it: for example if I press M-g g it gives me the error C-M-g is undefined which is true: Ctrl+Alt+g is undefined but I only pressed Alt+g why does emacs add the Crtl key to my combination?